TYPO3 Jobfair Undefined array key attachment
Jobfair extension is working until the moment when i try to send the application form, i got the error, in error log it looks:
Exception: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "attachment" in /home/typo3conf/ext/jobfair/Classes/Controller/JobController.php line 543
My site is on:
PHP 8.3
TYPO3 12.4.19
Jobfair 5.0.2

This issue is already known https://github.com/nhovratov/jobfair/issues/34 and "just" needs a fix as Pull Request
This will most likely be to change line 543 in JobController to $arguments['newApplication']['attachment'] = $arguments['attachment'] ?? [];

After suggested change i have another errr: Exception: Call to a member function getOriginalResource() on null, in file /home/t3_source_for_symlinks/typo3_src-12.4.19/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php:722 - {"exception":"Error: Call to a member function getOriginalResource() on null in /home/typo3conf/ext/jobfair/Classes/Controller/JobController.php:648

Most likely a follow up problem. It is very unlikely, you will get a full bugfix for the problem on Stackoverflow. This is a known bug in the extension and needs to be fixed - either by the extension author or someone who has knowledge/time.
If this is important for you to work, try to contact the extension author and ask for paid support/bugfix.
